# wordpress migration to new VM instance GCP

Tags: mysql, wordpress, google-cloud-platform, lamp, bitnami

seeking advice to  deploy my wordprees site on a new GCP vm.

the previous vm is down it was wordpress certified by bitnami click to deploy on Debian.

the vm got suspend and after reinstated its not accessible throw ssh.

so i create new ubuntu vm and mount the debian disk to take the files to the new vm.

i copied the wordpress folders to the new vm and i used new database.

i got the plugins and theme but no pages or photos or  products or setting.

now i need to transfer the database to mysql in ubuntu.

the path of the files is
mounted/opt/bitnami/mysql/data/bitnami_wordpress

my new vm mysql path is
/var/lib/mysql

Comment: PLEASE make the effort to use dots to create sentences. the text is hard to understand like that!

Comment: ok jasie thanks for feedback

Comment: Please follow the [steps](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-a-mysql-database-between-two-servers) here for transferring a database between virtual private servers can be accomplished using a SCP (Secure Copy), a method of copying files derived from the SSH Shell. If you require SSH access to your initial VM, then please use this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh#move_boot_disk) to recover the instance.

Comment: thanks Daud, Troubleshooting SSH is not resolving my issue,  Use disk on a new instance may help but i need to move to the new vm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wordpress migration to new VM instance GCP mysql not running after migration

My site got unauthorized redirect, I have edited the theme php files then the **GCP** ssh dead ?!

I have followed the same again as my question

I create new vm wordpress certified by bitnami

Stop the 2 VM instance

```
gcloud config set project my-pro
gcloud beta compute instances detach-disk old --disk old --zone namezone
gcloud beta compute instances attach-disk new --disk old --zone namezone
```

Start the new VM instance

```
sudo mkdir /old-disk
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /old-disk/
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh stop
sudo cp -r /deb-disk/opt/bitnami /opt
sudo umount /dev/sdb1
```

Stop the 2 VM instance

```
gcloud beta compute instances detach-disk new --disk old --zone namezone
gcloud beta compute instances attach-disk old --disk old --zone namezone --boot
```

Kindly advice as the VM is down and i need to restore it asap

#########################

Thanks echo resolved after executing

```
sudo tail -n40 /opt/bitnami/mysql/data/mysqld.log
```

and i got to know the permission is not enough

```
[ERROR] [MY-010958] [Server] Could not open log file.
[ERROR] [MY-010041] [Server] Can't init tc log
[ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
```

so i execute

```
sudo chmod 777 /opt/bitnami/mysql/data
sudo chown mysql:root -R /opt/bitnami/mysql/data
sudo find /opt/bitnami/mysql/data -type d -exec chmod 750 {} \;
sudo find /opt/bitnami/mysql/data -type f -exec chmod 640 {} \;
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start
```

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Engineer here,

Every time a user wants to migrate the WordPress content to a new instance, we suggest them use the All in One WordPress Migration plugin. You will simply need to export the data in your current instance

[image]

and export it later in the new instance you launch

[image]

If you had any other customization in the instance (SSL certificates, redirection, ...), you will need to apply those changes in the new instance as well.

You can learn more about that [here](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/how-to/migrate-wordpress/).

Comment: thanks jota, the problem is i don't have access to the wordpress on the old vm to export the site

Comment: Sorry Selim, thought you recovered the VM. If you still have access to the old VM disk, you can copy the entire /opt/bitnami directory to a new VM and start the services. You can compress the entire installation directory using tar and extract them later. You can learn more about that [here](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/apps/wordpress/administration/backup-restore/)

Comment: shall i follow the instruction in this topic   https://community.bitnami.com/t/instructs-for-installing-lamp-on-ubuntu/64742

Comment: waiting for your guidance, Thanks

Comment: The instructions you mentioned refer to the LAMP installation. Did you take a look at my previous comment? If you still have access to the old VM disk, you can copy the files to a new instance and start the services. Did you try that?

Comment: I uncompressed the files to var/www/project, i got ftp access to opt/bitnami

Comment: If the original instance had the installation folder at /opt/bitnami, you will need to uncompress the tar.gz containing the installation folder using the /opt/bitnami folder as well. If you use a different path, the services won't run.

Comment: Thanks jota Martos, i create a new VM wordpress certified by bitnami and uncompressed the files to the path  /opt/bitnami and its working

Comment: i have deleted /opt/bitnami/apps/phpmyadmin by mistake how to install it back

Comment: i have deleted /opt/bitnami/phpmyadmin by mistake also how to install it back

Comment: Hi @Selim, you can launch a new instance in the cloud (or a VM locally) and copy the phpmyadmin folder from one instance to the other one.

Comment: Hi Jota, 
i have excute **sudo cp -r /disk/opt/bitnami/apps/phpmyadmin /opt/bitnami/apps/phpmyadmin** so i got in the home page 

Awesome! WordPress is now installed. Access WordPress
You just installed WordPress using Bitnami.

I have this error
**Error: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in phar:///opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/bin/wp-cli.phar/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1169) : eval()'d code on line 63**

Comment: Hi @Selim, that's a separate issue. We suggest you create a new thread in [our community forum](https://community.bitnami.com) so our engineers can review your configuration and logs.

Comment: https://community.bitnami.com/t/bitnami-gcp-mysql-not-running-after-migration/90231/13